# Stripe PHP Webhook Test TLS Error & 502 Error

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am attempting to setup a webhook with the stripe-php library that will detect a "checkout.session.completed" event.  For some reason, I keep getting errors while testing the webhook on the Stripe site.

My server is running Centos 7 and PHP 7.2.21.  I've literally tried to replace my webhook with code to just give a HTTP 200 status code and it still gives the error.  Also, I recently installed my SSL certificate on this server.

```
<?php
http_response_code(200);
?>
```

The code above works perfectly fine in my browser when I access the link but for some reason still gives me this error on Stripe.

https://i.gyazo.com/f659d8fe4bfe53b84a592ec6009199a0.png
("TLS Failure")

It will also give me this error periodically, without changing the code at all:

https://i.gyazo.com/eef09716e18d1e0de692c5a102076c1b.png
("502 Error")

I've been trying to figure this out for the past 2 hours and haven't had any luck.

Thanks,

Jake

Edit:  Thanks to Paul, I was able to boil my issue down to something wrong with my server.  Instead of using webhooks, I've decided to just poll for successful checkout events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe requires you to use TLS 1.2 to successfully work. You can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html to test your SSL certificates if you are unsure about what you're running.

The fact that you are getting intermittent 502 errors suggests that there's something else going on with your server. You should check your server logs to see if you can find out why.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Paul.  Here are my test results: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=jchems.com&s=199.193.252.120&latest and here is an image of the results: https://i.gyazo.com/4276f22dc7be65924983b70dcf29a27e.png I will have to check the server logs and see if I can find out what's up.

Comment: SSLlabs is showing that you might have 2 servers associated with that domain. Did you switch IP addresses recently? If so there might be an issue with Stripe caching DNS lookups when sending webhooks. If that's the case you should reach out to Stripe support at https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: That's probably it.  I didn't change IP recently but I did recently buy my domain name.  I will contact Stripe support.  Thank you, Paul.